# Как вывести текст в цикле так, чтобы он отображался на каждой итерации?

Tags: php

Как вывести текст в цикле так, чтобы он отображался на каждой итерации?

Есть код:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo date("H:i:s");
    sleep(1);
}
```

Выведет:

```
16:38:01
16:38:02
16:38:03
16:38:04
...
16:38:10
```

Выведет после завершения цикла. Нужно чтобы выводились те же значения сразу, а не после завершения цикла. Подскажите, как это лучше сделать. Буду благодарен за кусочек кода

Comment: >>буфер надо отключать, причем на уровне php_value в апаче. (htaccess например)

Можешь представить кусочек кода?

Comment: в .htaccess

    php_value output_buffering Off
    php_value zlib.output_compression Off

Comment: Вроде то, что нужно, но одно но, у меня теперь криво отображается картинка, передаю ее так:

$above = getimagesize('2.jpg');
header('Content-type: '.$above['mime']);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile('2.jpg');

Comment: >>если вы хотите аяксом подтягивать значения (что, поверьте, вам не надо), то скрипт должен выдавать значение один раз, но подтягиваться аяксом он должен десять раз.

Мне нужно сделать плавный вывод времени, как тут:
http://sch.4com.su/sch_anim.php

Comment: @netuser, там это сделано *без* PHP, на js. Что и правильно.

---

disregard this

там вообще выводится **гифка**

Comment: Хм, как это реализовано? В словах.

Answer (score 1):

все работает, просто вы перед ++ пропустили "i"

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo date("H:i:s").'<br/>';
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Да не, не в этом дело. Я писал на скорую руку, поэтому пропустил. Все равно не работает.

Comment: @netuser ну не знаю у меня прекрасно работает
18:02:31
18:02:32
18:02:33
18:02:34
18:02:35
18:02:36
18:02:37
18:02:38
18:02:39
18:02:40

Comment: Ок, наверное, неправильно выразился. Мне нужно, чтобы скрипт выдавал значение СРАЗУ на каждой итерации, а так он выдает после прохода всего цикла.

Comment: И еще добавлю, доступа к php.ini у меня нет.

Comment: @netuser php серверный язык %)

Comment: Да это понятно, что это нужно делать на аяксе. Я хочу сделать что-то типа такого, вывод происходит на картинку, http://sch.4com.su/sch_anim.php.

Comment: буфер надо отключать, причем на уровне php_value в апаче.  (htaccess например)

Comment: @netuser, если вы хотите аяксом подтягивать значения (что, поверьте, вам не надо), то скрипт должен выдавать значение **один** раз, но подтягиваться аяксом он должен **десять** раз.